# what is the difference between 'incantation ' and 'invocation'

Tags: word-choice

What do we call the action of calling God's name(s) praying to Him for curing a disease. Is it incantation or invocation or something else?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Zeeshan. We expect people to do a little research before posting a question. If the research doesn't make everything clear, please add links to your research and explain specifically what you don't understand. In this case, you could look the words up in a good dictionary like this one: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incantation. In this case, the difference comes from the latin words in the middle: cantus = song or chant, vox = voice. So the right word depends on whether you sing or say God's name.

Answer (score 1):

An incantation is a chanted phrase.  An invocation is a summoning, a calling-by-name.  An incantation can be employed in an invocation; invocation can be the purpose of the incantation.